# kendodropdownlist not binding value to model after post

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-dropdown

I'm using kendo UI for my project. I have a kendo dropdownlist that I'm populating with json. I get the values in my dropdownlist but on post, the model doesn't get the selected value of the dropdownlist. I have been stuck on it for a day with no result. I'm not sure where I'm going. Please review the code

View:

```
      @model IEnumerable<EntityFrameworkClasses.StaggingException>



                @foreach (var item in Model)
    {




        @(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(modelItem => item.Level2)
                  .Name("Level2")
                  .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:10%" })
                  .OptionLabel("Select level 2...")
                  .DataTextField("Text")
                  .DataValueField("Value")
                  .BindTo((System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewBag.Level2)

        )
}


@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)
    .Name("CashExceptionsGridTest")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {



        columns.Bound(p => p.Category).Title("Category").Width(130);
        columns.Bound(p => p.EnterText1).Title("Comments").Width(130);
        columns.Bound(p => p.Dateoftransaction).Title("Date").Width(130);
        columns.Bound(p => p.InternalLocalAmount).Title("InternalAmt").Width(130);
        columns.Bound(p => p.ExternalLocalAmount).Title("ExternalAmt").Width(130);

    })
          .ToolBar(toolbar =>
                {
                     //toolbar.Template("<a class='k-button k-button-icontext' onclick='customCommand()' href='#'></span>Cutom Command</a>");

                         toolbar.Create(); // The "create" command adds new data items.
                          toolbar.Save();// The "save" command saves the changed data items.

                      })
        .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell)) // Use in-cell editing mode.
        .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height: 550px;" })



    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height: 350px;" })
    .Pageable(pageable => pageable
    .Input(true)
    .Numeric(false)
    )
           .Reorderable(r => r.Columns(true))
             .Sortable()
             .ColumnMenu()
             .Scrollable(scr => scr.Height(430))
             .Filterable()
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
    .Ajax()
    .PageSize(20)
    .ServerOperation(false)


                 .Batch(true) // Enable batch updates.
                           .Model(model =>
                                {
                                    model.Id(p => p.RowID); // Specify the property which is the unique identifier of the model.
                                    model.Field(p => p.RowID).Editable(false); // Make the ProductID property not editable.
                                })



              .Update("Editing_Update", "MultiTab")
              .Create("Editing_Create", "MultiTab")
               )




)
}
```

I have a kendo grid below which im not including for code brevity.

Controller:

```
  public ActionResult GetLevel()
            {
       IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Level2 = db2.StaggingInternalCashExceptions.Where(x=>x.LoadID==loadid).Select(c => new SelectListItem
            {

                Value = c.Level2.ToString(),
                Text = c.Level2

            }).Distinct();

            return  View();

            }

  [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
         public ActionResult Editing_Create([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, [Bind(Prefix = "models")]IEnumerable<StaggingException> results)
         if (results != null && ModelState.IsValid)
         {
             foreach (var result in results)
              var entity = new StaggingException();
                     entity.RowID = result.RowID;
                     entity.Category = result.Category; //this is a textbox in the view for which i get the value
                     entity.Level1 = result.Level1; //gives null
//I'm adding those values to the db. Didn't include all that for the sake of keeping it short.
}
}
```

The grid has batch editing, once i hit on save changes, the grid's data is posted to the controller where i can see it in results. I cannot get the dropdown value though.
Any ideas or leads please.
Thank you.

Comment: I'm assuming this is a partial view - I noticed that your action is specifying a bind prefix - is the partial view being called with the same prefix?

Comment: @sleeyuen: It isn't a partial view. I want to show a dropdownlist and a kendo grid in the same view. I binded the dropdown list to the model using @Html.kendo.DropdownListFor(modelItem=>item.Level1), yet on post I cannot get the selected value of the dropdown which is puzzling.

Comment: OK - next thing I would check is if the form is actually posting anything to your controller (via Chrome Dev Tools, Fiddler, etc.). If data is being posted, include it here so I can get a better understanding of where the breakdown may be.

Comment: @sleeyuen: I added more code. To put it in a fiddler, that'll be slightly hard because of the whole models. I put a debug point at the action method, I can see the grid data in results but I cannot get the selected dropdown value.

Comment: I think I understand what you've got here, but to confirm, could you post an image of the rendered page. I didn't mean to create a working fiddle - I meant to use a program called Fiddler to see what data is being passed from the browser to your controller, much the same way that you can use the Network tab on Chrome/IE Dev Tools to inspect network activity.

Answer (score 2):

Late to this post but I have had a similar issue, for those with the same problem of the value not being posted in the model, if your model value is a nullable int? (can't see from the above post...) then you need to configure the DropDownListFor as below to avoid the default value binding behavior to update the field with the selected item when the initial value is null. Hope this helps someone.

```
Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m)
.HtmlAttributes(new { data_value_primitive = "true" })
```